# How to get the bluetooth MAC address in iOS 3.2 and later?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, mac-address

I want to get the bluetooth MAC address in iOS 3.2 and later, but can't find any usable way, could someone give me some advices?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exposed publicly, not even at the level of BSD sockets.

Why do you think you need it? Perhaps we can suggest an alternative approach if you tell us what your goal is.