# Bluetooth MAC Address reading from iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, bluetooth, mac-address

I need to know the Bluetooth MAC address of an iOS device, is there any way this data is accessible?

The purpose would be to identify when any user gets near that Bluetooth device.

In case this isn't possible in any way, what alternatives should I take into account?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the bluetooth MAC address in iOS 3.2 and later?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278918/how-to-get-the-bluetooth-mac-address-in-ios-3-2-and-later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible with iOS public APIs